Laravel dispatch job only triggered when other dispatch is called
The laravel dispatch job is only triggered when another dispatch is called.
Here is the code:
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SimpleJob implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message = "Default message")
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("SimpleJob executed with message: " . $this->message);

        echo "SimpleJob executed with message: " . $this->message . "\n";
    }
}

And when I use tinker to debug
dispatch(new App\Jobs\SimpleJob("Delayed Job!"));

It didn't run at all until the next time I called dispatch.


first set the queue_connection to database and you have to make sure the "php artisan queue:work" command is added in the supervisor so if any job will be added into jobs table it will automatically process it.
